# How to Implement Multiple Pages in a TableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview, uipagecontrol

I'm a bit stumped on what route to start implementing a new design.  Essentially there is a tableview with multiple cells that have page controls.

I'm thinking to create a scrollview with separate classes and xib files, but not really sold on that solution.

[image]

Each of these cells is a tableview where I'll have to have dynamic content pulled from the database on each of the pages.

I'm not really sure what route to take and would love to hear some ideas of what would be the most effective solution.

Comment: Put a collection view and a page control in each row of your table

Comment: Not positive a collection view would be best because some of the views have different styling and variables

Comment: You are going to have to create the various views anyway. Having them in collection view cells doesn't really change that.  All of the paging, scrolling and view dequing will be handled by the collection view

Comment: I would do the same like @Paulw11 XIB files are tricky to handle. When you implement them you have to set constraints programmatically. With constraints a scrollview can be very tricky, too. You will find a bunch of posts where people can't handle a scrollview the right way. CollectionView do this for you.